# Apache 2.4 mod_rewrite and RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} empty

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So far I've been using

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =""
```

or

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !.*=.*
```

as condition to check is my query string empty before applying rewrite rule. As of Apache 2.4 these directives no longer work.

For example, for my http://test.loc/ address mod_rewrite log output is as follows:

```
RewriteCond: input='ver=1.0' pattern='=""' => not-matched, referer: http://test.loc/
```

or when using second directive

```
RewriteCond: input='ver=1.0' pattern='!.*=.*' => not-matched, referer: http://test.loc/
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this with regex:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(input=[^&]*)?$
```

Comment: Thanks but log results are: RewriteCond: input='ver=3.7' pattern='^$' => not-matched, referer: http://test.loc/

Comment: Where is `input='ver=3.7'` coming from?

Comment: It's just copy/paste from error.log with LogLevel mod_rewrite.c:trace8

Comment: I suspect `input='ver=1.0'` is being added some where. Try edited answer.

Comment: Thanks for your time, your comment pointed me in the direction that I was reading logs incorrectly. The error was in another rewrite condition.